# Can I close/reconnect zkhandle inside a zookeeper watcher?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

As far as I know, ZK will do watcher function in another thread. So is it safe to close zkhandle inside a watcher(say it received a session expired event)

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out fine when doing that. However there is still one thread remain after calling zookeeper_close